# Installed Ubuntu ; can't acess Windows any more

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot

I have windows vista, and I downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 and burned it onto a blank cd disk. I then went through the installation process by clicking install Ubuntu on the menu that popped up after booting from my disk. I then selected the option that said install alongside windows vista.

This is where it gets weird. It gave me the partition creator/slider option to decide how much data I needed for windows and Ubuntu. It displayed only like a total of 10 gigabytes, giving windows vista around 6 gigs, and Ubuntu 12.04 around 4 gigs. My computer has a 500 gigabyte hard drive so I have no idea why it gave me such small numbers.

After clicking next I decided that I should restart with the "create your own partitions" option so I restarted the computer and booted straight back into the disk I had Ubuntu on. I made a 500mb Linux swap partition, and a 25GB primary ex4/journaling partition mounted at /. I selected that partition, and the installation process began.

It was installing okay until towards the end, when it froze. The mouse pointer was no longer moving and the loading animation was not spinning anymore. I waited around ten minutes and nothing happened so I force shut down the computer.

I repeated the whole installation process remaking the partitions, and Ubuntu finally installed. The installer told me to restart the computer so I did. When it booted up it gave me a screen that said "frequency out of range" I couldn't do anything with my computer.

After that I restarted my computer again and after going to the frequency out of range screen, it actually booted Ubuntu.

Overall, I now have a computer that SOMETIMES boots to Ubuntu, and I  can't boot into windows at all. This is a serious problem because all of my parents stuff and my stuff is on windows. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Since you messed up with your partition, you'd better first recover your Windows partition before you deal with this "frequency out of range" error.

Use your Windows installation disk to boot you computer and select `repair your computer` option  below `Install Now` button. After that you need to select `Startup Repair` option.  If ever things go correct, you can boot into Windows.
More about Windows recovery can be found on the Microsoft [website.](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-vista)

After that you can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) to get rid of "frequency out of range" error.

1. Install and run Boot-Repair from a liveCD or liveUSB
2. Click Advanced options
3. Reinstall GRUB
4. Go to the GRUB options tab
5. Tick the out-of-range option
6. Apply
   Reboot your system.

Comment: What if I want to get rid of Ubuntu completely and go back to the way my computer was?

Comment: Skip the Boot-Repair part.

Comment: Ok and for the first  part you're saying I find the disk windows came on and I boot from it and it will give me te option for startup repair?

Comment: ok. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Problem: when I run te disk windows came on it opens to an "Install Windows" tab and asks me to enter the language, time and currency format, and keyboard input method. There is no option to run startup repair

Comment: Update: I just hit next and it gave me the option to repair. I ran startup repair and it did not detect a problem. How can I fix this please help

Comment: OK. Try  repair ->command prompt, enter:
`BootRec.exe /fixmbr` or refer [this](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/17521-how-fix-mbr-through-command-prompt.html).